# sed: delete lines that match a pattern in a given field

Tags: sed, field, matching

I have a file tab delimited that looks like this:

```
##INFO=<ID=AC1,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="Max-likelihood">
##INFO=<ID=MQ,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Root-mean-square">
##INFO=<ID=FQ,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="Phred probability">
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT
53_344  2   .   C   G   999     .   .   GT:PL:DP:DPR
6_56775 67  .   T   A   999     .   .   GT:PL:DP:DPR
53_234  78  .   CCG GAT 999     .   .   GT:PL:DP:DPR
45_569  5   .   TCCG    GTTA    999     .   .   GT:PL:DP:DPR
3_67687 2   .   T   G   999     .   .   GT:PL:DP:DPR
53_569  89  .   T   G   999     .   .   GT:PL:DP:DPR
```

I am trying to use sed to delete all the lines that contain more than one letter in the 4th field (in the case above, line 7 and 8 from the top). I have tried the following regular expression but there must be a glitch some where that I cannot find:

```
sed '5,${;/\([^.]*\t\)\{3\}\[A-Z][A-Z]\+\t/d;}' input.vcf>new.vcf
```

The syntax is as follows:

- 5,$  #start at line 5 until the end of the file ($)
- ([^.]*\t) #matching group is any single character followed by a zero or more characters followed by a tab.
- {3} #previous block repeated 3 times (presumably for the 4th field)
- [A-Z][A-Z]+\t #followed by any string of two letters or more followed by a tab.

Unfortunately, this doesn' t work but I know I am close to make it to work. Any hints or help will make this a great teaching moment.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `awk` is okay for you, you can use below command:

```
 awk '(FNR<5){print} (FNR>=5)&&length($4)<=1' input.vcf
```

Default delimiter is `space`, you can use -F"\t" to switch it to tab, put it after `awk`. for instance, `awk -F"\t" ....`

`(FNR<5){print}` FNR is file number record, when it is less than 5, print the whole line

`(FNR>=5) && length($4)<=1` will handle the rest lines and filter lines which 4th field has one character or less.

Output:

```
##INFO=<ID=AC1,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="Max-likelihood">
##INFO=<ID=MQ,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Root-mean-square">
##INFO=<ID=FQ,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="Phred probability">
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT
53_344  2   .   C   G   999     .   .   GT:PL:DP:DPR
6_56775 67  .   T   A   999     .   .   GT:PL:DP:DPR
3_67687 2   .   T   G   999     .   .   GT:PL:DP:DPR
53_569  89  .   T   G   999     .   .   GT:PL:DP:DPR
```

You can redirect the output to an output file.

Comment: in the original file, delimiter is `\t`, it's just that copy/paste lost them, but iyour solution works in both cases. awk suits better for this problem.

Comment: I studied your response and, although I am not proficient in awk, I realize what you and Jean-Francois said. awk is probably better suited for this kind of manipulation. In this particular case, awk syntax make wonderful sense. Thank you Haifeng. Very much appreciated for this lesson.

Comment: Be careful with this - notice that the `#CHROM` 4th header line has vanished from the output and if your 3rd description line ended in `Description="Phred probability over time">` or any other couple of white spaces appeared that line would be deleted too. It's not implementing your `start at line 5 ` requirement.

Comment: I am glad you notice. How come it did not start at line 5?

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for pointing out that:)  I have fixed the command

Comment: You're welcome `(FNR<5){print} (FNR>=5)&&length($4)<=1` can be reduced to just `(FNR<5) || (length($4)<=1)` though. Parens added just for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed your sed filter (took me a while almost went crazy over it)

```
5,${/^\([^\t]\+\t\)\{3\}[A-Z][A-Z]\+\t/d}
```

Your errors:

```
[^.]*: everything but a dot.
```

Thanks to Ed, now I know that. I thought dot had to be escaped, but that does not seem to apply between brackets. Anyhow, this could match a tabulation char and match 2 or 3 groups instead of one, failing to match your line (regex are greedy by default)

```
\[A-Z][A-Z]: bad backslash. What did it do? hum, dunno!
```

test:

```
$ sed '5,${/^\([^\t]\+\t\)\{3\}[A-Z][A-Z]\+\t/d}' foo.Txt
##INFO=<ID=AC1,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="Max-likelihood">
##INFO=<ID=MQ,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Root-mean-square">
##INFO=<ID=FQ,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="Phred probability">
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT
53_344  2       .       C       G       999     .   .   GT:PL:DP:DPR
6_56775 67      .       T       A       999     .   .   GT:PL:DP:DPR
3_67687 2       .       T       G       999     .       .       GT:PL:DP:DPR
53_569  89  .   T   G   999     .   .   GT:PL:DP:DPR
```

conclusion: to process delimited fields, `awk` is better :)

Comment: I studied your comments to my errors: 2) I did put the backslash to separate from the previous argument {3\}. But I guess the alphanumeric group is "within" the regular expression and not separate from it. I don' t know if I explained myself properly here, but your solution makes sense now. 1) I still do not understand why "[^.]*" would not work. I interpret it this way:" at the beginning of the line (^), any single character (.), followed by zero or more previous characters (*)." That's why I do not understand what I am interpreting wrong. Anyway, merci beaucoups Jean-Francois. I appreciated.

Comment: `[^.]*` means `any character except a period repeated zero or more times`. The caret `^` is the negation operator when used inside a bracket expression `[...]`. Outside of a bracket expression it means `start of string` which of course means `start of line` when used in sed since sed operates one line at a time so each string is a line (barring hold space/buffer nonsense that became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented). Maybe you meant to write `^.*` which means `zero or more repetitions of any character at the start of a line` (only useful in capture groups)? Or `^.+` or `^.{2,}`?

Comment: I learned something on regexes today. I always escaped the dots in brackets. Hold buffer nonsense? You mean commands like g,h,G,H,x? I love them: they render sed scripts so cryptic :)

Comment: Exactly. If you're using sed commands other than s, g, and p (with -n) then you should be using awk instead. (I've been using sed for ~35 years and awk for ~25 so I have some experience!).

Comment: BTW the `[^.]*` thing may have generated a "greedy" effect, preventing the match. I have edited my answer to explain that. I was using `sed` a lot because I read a doc called "do it with sed" which explained all the crazy things you shouldn't do with sed but could do so I did them :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR<5 || $4~/^.$/' file
##INFO=<ID=AC1,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="Max-likelihood">
##INFO=<ID=MQ,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Root-mean-square">
##INFO=<ID=FQ,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="Phred    probability">
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT
53_344  2       .       C       G       999     .       .       GT:PL:DP:DPR
6_56775 67      .       T       A       999     .       .       GT:PL:DP:DPR
3_67687 2       .       T       G       999     .       .       GT:PL:DP:DPR
53_569  89      .       T       G       999     .       .       GT:PL:DP:DPR
```

Comment: Thank you Ed for this insight. If you have time would you mind breaking down the code in a few words ? I am just realizing what awk can do and I am looking for a start up. Thanks. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. It just implements exactly what you wrote in your bullet list requirements (minus all the unnecessary stuff you'd have to consider if you were to use sed instead of awk) which is to print all lines where `NR<5` = "they occur before line 5", `||` = "or", `$4~/^.$/` = "the 4th field is just one character". I highly recommend the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins if you're going to be doing any text manipulation at any time in your life.

Comment: Great insight. I already got the book from the library. Thank you very much.